# Use photos from stocks as drawing reference

Tags: reference, drawing, photoshop, stock

I was reading books of digital art, and in one of these books it is said that it is necessary to use images as a reference for drawing.
I found several stocks selling images, it is illegal if i use one of them without buying to use as a reference?

Example: I need to draw a body of a woman on some position, i look for a woman on the stock and draw something like that.

sry for bad english guys :x
hope someone help me

Answer (score 0):

if you draw it by yourself it is legal, but if you downloaded it and used it voiding the copyright terms boy you can get yourself in trouble unless its for some local projects and your institute allows using stolen contents from net,

you can use stock images without removing watermarks and signatures but you should give credits to the creator for their hard work

also you can find a lot of free alternate resource in net,